# How can I make a method in class on Ruby? And I want to use in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

It is such a shame that I can't figure out how solve this and ask for help, but I need your help.
I am woking on a project and I don't know how to make a method in class on Ruby.

by using the method below, I could do what I wanted to do.

```
string = １２３４
NKF.nkf('-X -w', string).tr('０-９ａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ', '0-9a-zA-Z') # => '1234'
```

now I want to make this class method so I can use them repeatedly in different place.(because it looks kind of long)

In order to solve this, I tried to make a method called modify_string like below.
(code is a bit changed )

```
(author.class)
def modify_string(ids)
   ids.tr('０-９ａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ', '0-9a-zA-Z').gsub('、',',').split(',')
end

scope :search_user, lambda {| user_id|
   results = self.where(id: user_id.modify_string(ids))}
```

but it called an error that says "undefined method `modify_string' for "６６":String

６６ is sent from input on html.erb and when I wrote the code below, it perfectly works.

```
scope :search_user, lambda {| user_id|
   results = self.where(id: user_id.tr('０-９ａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ', '0-9a-zA-Z').gsub('、',',').split(',')
)}
```

I want to make a good method for this somehow.

Would you please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: It seems you may wish to create a module with module methods. Consider, for example, the [Math](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Math.html) module. All the methods in this module are module methods (think functions), involked with `Math` as their receiver, such as `Math.sqrt(3)`.  (That module is never included in a class.) Perhaps you want something like `module NKF; def self.my_method(str); ....; end; end`, with `my_method` invoked (from anywhere) `x = NKF.my_method("Little Miss Muffet")`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment.
like you told me, I tried to make a file and made a method and it completely worked.
Thank you.

class String
  def modify
    to_han = tr('０-９ａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ', '0-9a-zA-Z')

  end
end


p "ｂｌａｂｌａｂｌａ、ｙｅｈａｙｅａｈｙｅａｈ".modify

but I can't still use it in the class as I mentioned earlier the class Author

Would you please kindly tell me how?
Thank you.

Comment: Adding methods to Ruby's core classes (such as `Array`, `String`, `Hash`), called *monkeypatching*, is generally not a good idea. Suppose, for example, a future version of Ruby came with a method whose name is the same as the method you've added. If you want to do that, however, just write, say, `class String; def my_method(..); ...; end; end`; that is you simple "open" the class `String`, define the method and close the class with `end`. If you do that your method will be called on a string: `"Mary had a little lamb".my_method(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments again. I appreciate that.
So I should change the name of the class to something like 'Modify' class.
but I don't know how to use it in class Author. 
thank you for your help I definitely need to study more though.